# Suspend main thread in C or infinity sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, sleep, program-entry-point

I want my thread to run forever. Somewhere in the code, if 'BYE' is received, it will kill the whole process. When I use `while(TRUE)` or `for(;;)` I see 25% increment in CPU usage. sleep function is also limited. Any idea?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Run the Standard Input/Output to reply to the super application 
    // (interface probably written in C#)
    thread_standardIO_i = pthread_create(
        &thread_standardIO_thrd, 
        NULL, 
        stdio_thread, 
        NULL);

    while (1){
    }

    //sleep(9999999);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "limited" mean to you? Why can't you sleep?

Comment: If your Input/Output thread terminates, there is no way to receive the BYE command in the first place, so why not (a) just join that thread, or better still (b) make the main thread the Input/Output thread and exit the process when BYE is received). It would literally be as simple as *invoking* `stdio_thread` rather than spinning a thread and trying to shoe-string a "wait" paradigm.

Comment: Maybe POSIX [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html)?

Comment: while (!sleep(999)); will loop until the process gets a signal which causes sleep to return the amount of time left to sleep instead.

Comment: mjan635, when you 'see 25% increment in CPU usage'; is that what you expected? If not, what is your target impact on CPU utilization?

Comment: A 'sleep(9999999);' while-loop is not unreasonable.  CPU usage will be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `pthread_join` some other thread that will also last the lifetime of the application, or `pthread_cond_wait` a condvar that is never signalled? Those operations will block the thread "forever", unlike `sleep` which simply asks for it to be woken up "in a while".

Comment: Because of possible "spurious wakeups" `pthread_cond_wait` must also be run in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sleep inside a infinite loop, sleep value helps in setting CPU usage consumed by infinite loop.

```
while(1)
{
sleep(1); // set sleep value as u wish
}
```

Comment: This is not an infinite sleep. It wakes up all the time.